# How to select a specific number of random records in Salesforce per day?

Tags: random, salesforce, apex-code, soql, force.com

Scenario:
Each day Salesforce users create x number of new opportunities. At the end of the day, I would like to create a function (Workflow/APEX trigger etc.) to randomly select 3 of opportunities that were created in that day to send a survey to.

Conceptually i feel like this is possible, but I have never done something like this so I am not sure if it is.

Answer (score 1):

First get a count of the records created that day.

```
Integer size = Database.getCountQuery('select count() from Opportunity where CreatedDate = TODAY');
```

Then use `OFFSET` to get your random record.

```
Integer offset = Math.floor(Math.random() * size).intValue();
Opportunity randomOppty = [select Id from Opportunity where CreatedDate = TODAY LIMIT 1 OFFSET :offset];
```

You'll have to randomize `offset` for each SOQL call.